# RxJava not running in UniTest Android (Not androidTest)

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-android

I newbiew about rxjava and play RxJava in Unitest, but the Observable not running.

```
@Test
fun notepad(){
    val scheduler = TestScheduler()
    val subscriber = TestObserver<String>()
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler{ scheduler }
    Single.just("Data Local")
        .toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map { "Map Local" }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .flatMap { Observable.just(1) }
        .map { "Map Remote" }
        .startWith { "StartWith" }
        .onErrorReturn { "Error Return" }
        .subscribe(subscriber)
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    print("${subscriber.hasSubscription()}")
}
```

but subscriber.hasSubscription() return false. how can i get the onNext value, or its because my Observable wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJava v2 has very useful method `test`. It provides functionality for testing your observables in easy way. Rewrite your test by this way and use many of assertion methods, that provide RxJava:

**Your edited code**

```
@Test
fun notepad(){
    val scheduler = TestScheduler()
    val subscriber = TestObserver<String>()
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler{ scheduler }
    Single.just("Data Local")
        .toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map { "Map Local" }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .flatMap { Observable.just(1) }
        .map { "Map Remote" }
        .startWith { "StartWith" }
        .onErrorReturn { "Error Return" }
        .test()
        .await()
        .assertValueAt(0) { startString->
                yourString == "StartWith"
            }
        .assertValueAt(1) { mapString->
                mapString == "Map Remote"
            }
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

If you want to learn about it more checkout [this link](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/testing-rxjava-code-made-easy-4cc32450fc9a)

Comment: but why always waiting .await() its mean my Observable not call onComplete?

Comment: No, `await` is needed when you have some operations separeted in several threads(like you use `Schedulers.computation()` in example). It waiting for value and only after that calling assertion methods.